# Center NSView after adding it to the superview with setFrameOrigin in Swift on OSX

Tags: xcode, swift, macos, cocoa

I am dynamically adding subviews to a superview during runtime and want to resize the superview to match the subview.  The resizing is working fine, but it's not centered when I add the subview.  The second view seems to be added where the first one ended.

This is a bit of code that is called multiple times and is passed different subViews:

```
    self.currentConstraints = [
        NSLayoutConstraint(item: superView, attribute: .Height, relatedBy: .Equal, toItem: nil, attribute: .NotAnAttribute, multiplier: 1.0, constant: subView.frame.size.height),
        NSLayoutConstraint(item: superView, attribute: .Width, relatedBy: .Equal, toItem: nil, attribute: .NotAnAttribute, multiplier: 1.0, constant: subView.frame.size.width)
    ]

    superView.addConstraints(self.currentConstraints!)

    addChildViewController(viewController)
    superView.addSubview(viewController.view)
```

I can get the subView to move around with `setFrameOrigin`, but that moves them both up or down based on where they wrongly positioned in the beginning.

Comment: If your view(s) participate in autolayout (ie. they have constraints), you should not be calling `setFrameOrigin:` to reposition things. Rather, you should set up constraints so that they're laid out correctly. (I don't think there's enough info in your question to know _exactly_ what you're trying to do and why it's not working.)

Comment: I agree with Andrew.  One can't really help you since you don't mention whether or not you use Auto Layout.

Comment: Is the better (more idiomatic) way to use autolayout for this type of thing?  I am using auto layout (and am using constraints above to resize it), so maybe I should stick with that?  Although if there's a more common way that embraces the framework more, I could switch both approaches.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I ended up ditching using constraints and using `setFrameSize` on the super view.  This approach I was skipping before because the popover it was in wasn't resizing, so I just set it as a delegate and had it resize when the new subview was added.

```
    superView.setFrameSize(subView.frame.size)

    self.delegate.subViewChanged(subView.frame.size)

    addChildViewController(viewController)
    superView.addSubview(viewController.view)
```